# I'm using DataTable Row grouping add on to display account related contacts in visualforce page

Tags: jquery, user-interface, datatable, salesforce, visualforce

I'm able to display only Account Name as header and onclick of it ,it's showing all contacts but now I want to display few columns from account in one row on click it should show it's contacts.

Now I want to display like below image where I need to show more columns related to account and under that account all contacts with heading.

Please see the below post for more information(For Images)

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/84721/issue-with-datatable-row-grouping-add-on-to-display-account-related-contacts-in

My JS code

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable({
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bJQueryUI": true
            }).rowGrouping({
                bExpandableGrouping: true,
                bExpandSingleGroup: false,
                iExpandGroupOffset: -1,
                asExpandedGroups: [""]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

As in the image

Thanks In advance.